# How to subscribe two images simultaneously in opencv c++

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used cv_bridge of opencv to subscribe image from kinect . I want to subscribe two images and send it to function. please tell me how to code it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179998/how-to-subscribe-two-images-simultaneously-in-opencv-c++/) by [deathstroke](https://answers.ros.org/users/19241/deathstroke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A (relatively fancy, with time sync etc.) way of doing what you request is implemented in stereo_image_proc. See disparity nodelet code [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/stereo_image_proc/src/nodelets/disparity.cpp). The nodelet subscribes to two images and generates a disparity map from them once a pair of them has been received ([in imageCb](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/stereo_image_proc/src/nodelets/disparity.cpp#L170)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2